# SQL query:Having number=max(number) doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have two tables,Writer and Books. A writer can pruduce many books. I want to get the **all** writers who produce maximal number of books.

Firstly, my sql query is like:

```
     SELECT Name FROM(
        SELECT Writer.Name,COUNT(Book.ID) AS NUMBER FROM Writer,Book
        WHERE
            Writer.ID=Book.ID
        GROUP BY Writer.Name
        )
        WHERE NUMBER=(SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM
                      (SELECT Writer.Name,COUNT(Book.ID) AS NUMBER FROM Writer,Book
                      WHERE Writer.ID=Book.ID
                      GROUP BY Writer.Name
        )
```

It works. However I think this query is too long and there exists some duplications. I want to make this query shorter. So I try another query like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM(
        SELECT Writer.Name,COUNT(Book.ID) AS NUMBER FROM Writer,Book
        WHERE
            Writer.ID=Book.ID
        GROUP BY Writer.Name
        HAVING NUMBER = MAX(NUMBER)
        )
```

However, this HAVING clause doesn't work and my sqlite says its an error.
I don't know why. Can anyone explain to me ? Thank you!

Comment: You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each query provides you with one level of aggregation, so you cannot use `Max` on `COUNT` in the same query. You need a sub-query like you did in your first query.

However, your first query can be simplified on MySQL to:

```
SELECT Writer.Name
FROM Writer, Book
WHERE Writer.ID = Book.ID
GROUP BY Writer.Name
HAVING COUNT(Book.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(Book.ID) AS n
                         FROM Writer, Book
                         WHERE Writer.ID = Book.ID
                         GROUP BY Writer.Name
                         ORDER BY n DESC
                         LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think it's ORDER BY NUMBER DESC,right?

Answer (score 3):

The `HAVING` clause provides filtering on the final set (typically after a group by) and does not provide additional grouping functionality.   Think of it just like a WHERE clause, but can be applied after a `GROUP BY`.

Your query with the `HAVING NUMBER = MAX(NUMBER)` implies grouping of the set of NUMBER values across all records and doesn't make sense in this example (even though we all get what you want it to do).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL (but not SQLite), you can use variables to reduce the amount of work and make a simpler query.  However, there are nuances there, because variables with `group by` require an extra level of subqueries:

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT t.*, (@m := if(@m = 0, NUMBER, @m)) as maxn
      FROM (SELECT w.Name, COUNT(b.ID) AS NUMBER
            FROM Writer w JOIN
                 Book b
                 ON w.ID = b.ID
            GROUP BY w.Name
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @m := 0) params
      ORDER BY NUMBER desc
     ) t
WHERE maxn = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are nesting aggregate functions, which is not allowed.

HAVING NUMBER = MAX(NUMBER) is like HAVING COUNT(Book.ID) = MAX(COUNT(Book.ID))

Nesting COUNT inside MAX seems to be the issue here